Kfold cross val in Regression model
How to use K-fold CV to evaluate my regression model performance to calculate the R2, MAE and MSE in the train set to make the model more robust? This code below refers to the tuned model and I'm using a set for train and another for testing. The following is my code after I preprocessed the data (filled missing and encoded):
parameters = {'n_estimators': [150],
          'random_state': [5],
          'max_features': [0.1],
          'max_depth': [100],
          'criterion': ['poisson']
          }

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

k_folds = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle=True, random_state = 77)


# base model
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor()

grid_search_cv= GridSearchCV(model, param_grid = parameters, cv = k_folds, scoring='r2', n_jobs = -1, verbose=3, refit = True)

result = grid_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)



best_model = result.best_estimator_



yhat = best_model.predict(X_test)

# Stock the result
data_acc = round(r2_score(np.array(y_test), yhat) ,3)

data_acc_train = metrics.r2_score(y_train, best_model.predict(X_train))

Given the results are as below, should I be worried with the difference of performance?


Are you asking why the training performance is much better than the test performance? This is by construction of a random forest (and a rather problematic property).

In fact, I want to know if I can use Kfold to make the evaluation for the train set more robust, or If I'm doing something wrong regarding this part.

@ViniciusMaia - Welcome to CV. I think you need to stratify your train-test by bins of observed data.  You have no test samples at the tails.  Eyeball suggest bin-splits at something like 5-degree increments, but you might want at least 1 test for every 4 training samples in the bin.  The simpler approach to CV is just rerun the whole thing (without set seed) and store the values.  If you rerun the whole thing say 30 times, with the 80/20 train-test split, then you can apply something like a JMP-style variability plot to look at variation in train-to-test fit quality by bins.
